# Problems running Sample SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Error:

`ORA-06550: line1, column 22:
PLS-00103 Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
* & = - + .......`

PL/SQL Block:

```
DECLARE v_c number :=0;
   BEGIN
      SELECT COUNT(*) into v_c from all_sequences where sequence_name='TEST_SEQ' and   sequence_owner='test';
      IF v_c = 1 THEN
         execute immediate 'DROP SEQUENCE test.TEST_SEQ';
      END IF;
   END;
/
```

Comment: Why `execute immediate`? Why not just do `THEN DROP SEQUENCE ...`?

Comment: @spikeX, you can't execute DDL in a PL/SQL block.

Comment: Also, adding a little bit of explanation or detail to the question would probably help. Don't just paste code.

Comment: where do you run it? there's a difference for example in toad, running it with f9 would cause this to happen but not with f5

Comment: There is no problem with your code that I can see save that the `test` should be `TEST` in `sequence_owner='test';`

Answer (score 4):

I copied the code from your post and ran it in both SQLDeveloper and SQLPlus with no problem:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production

```
prompt> DECLARE v_c number :=0;                        
  2     BEGIN
  3        SELECT COUNT(*) into v_c from all_sequences where sequence_name='TEST_SEQ' and sequence_owner='test';
  4        IF v_c = 1 THEN
  5           execute immediate 'DROP SEQUENCE test.TEST_SEQ';
  6        END IF;
  7     END;
  8  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

What tool are you using?  My best suggestion is try it in SQLPlus, and if you still have an error, show us the full text of the session.

Answer (score 4):

You are only executing the first line rather than the whole PL/SQL block.

```
DECLARE v_c number :=0
/
```

Resulting in:

```
DECLARE v_c number :=0
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 22:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the
following:
* & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
```

As others suggest, try this in SQLPlus.